# Plotting two line plots of different index lengths with disconnects where there is no data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have two data sets that I need to plot on a single pair of axes. Each data set contains two lists:

- Dates (in format of YYYYMM)
- Values (monthly averages)

The problem I am having is that one data set only contains summer months (plotted in red), while the other contains every month (plotted in blue). As a result, I get an image like the one below: [image: Red and blue line plots both extend continuously from left side to right side of a graph.]

However, I don't want the line plot for the summer months (red) to connect between years. That is, I don't want to draw a line between data points for 200208 and 200306. I want a gap in the red line where data does not exist, like this graph from [Joe Kuan](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/line-area-and-scatter-charts).

[image: Blue line has continuous data. Red line has breaks where no data exist.]

The code I used to plot the first image is:

```
#data1
x = monthly_avgs_aod.index.tolist()
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y%m') for i in x] 
y = monthly_avgs_aod.values.tolist()

#data2
q = monthly_avgs_pm.index.tolist()
q = [dt.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y%m') for i in q] 
w = monthly_avgs_pm.values.tolist()
plt.plot(q, w, '-r')    
plt.plot(x, y, ':b')
```

The data that I am using looks like this:

```
#data1
x=['200101','200102','200103','200104','200105','200106','200107','200108','200109','200110','200111','200112','200201','200202','200203','200204','200205','200206','200207','200208','200209']
y=[30.2,37.6,34.7,27.1,31.9,43.9,42.4,42.3,34.4,40.0,47.2,40.8,34.7,27.1,31.9,43.9,42.4,42.3,34.4,40.0,47.2]

#data2   
q=['200106','200107','200108','200206','200207','200208']
w=[19.7,18.6,15.2,17.3,16.9,18.2]
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution in a case like this where both lists of dates share the same dates (i.e. a month might either be in the list or not), would be to fill the list which contains only the summer months with `None` values at the positions where there is no data and plot it against the same `x` that the complete `y` list is plotted against.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
#data1
x=['200101','200102','200103','200104','200105','200106','200107','200108',
   '200109','200110','200111','200112','200201','200202','200203','200204',
   '200205','200206','200207','200208','200209']
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y%m') for i in x] 
y=[30.2,37.6,34.7,27.1,31.9,43.9,42.4,42.3,34.4,40.0,47.2,
   40.8,34.7,27.1,31.9,43.9,42.4,42.3,34.4,40.0,47.2]

#data2   
q=['200106','200107','200108','200206','200207','200208']
q = [dt.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y%m') for i in q] 
w=[19.7,18.6,15.2,17.3,16.9,18.2]

for i, xi in enumerate(x):
    if xi not in q:
        w.insert(i, None)


plt.plot(x,y, '-r')    
plt.plot(x,w,':b')


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `q = [z if z in q else None for z in x]`. You'd also have to apply `strptime` to `x` like you do to `q`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate list for each set of contiguous months. Plot each list separately.

```
sublist_q = [q.pop()] # algorithm reverses order, shouldn't matter
sublist_w = [w.pop()]
while q:
    # Just-popped last month is sublist_q[-1] .
    # Next-to-pop month preceding it in data is q[-1]%100 .
    # Represent next-to-pop December as 0 with q[-1]%100%12
    # so that contiguous months always have a difference of 1
    if sublist_q[-1] - q[-1]%100%12 != 1: # True if months not contiguous
        # We're done with the current sublists. 
        plot(sublist_q, sublist_w, 'r-o') # 'o' to show singletons
        # Reinitialize
        sublist_q = [q.pop()]
        sublist_w = [w.pop()]
    else:
        sublist_q.append(q.pop()) 
        sublist_w.append(w.pop())
```

Comment: itretools.groupby would be perfect for this.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby  but I think using itertools would use more memory and time.